# Existing duplicates not shown in report after enabling duplicate and matching rule

Tags: duplicate-management

The duplicate report is slowing only the duplicates which are inserted or modified after enabling duplicate rule and matching rule. It is not showing existing duplicate. Could anyone let ne know how to modify it in order to include existing duplicates in the report.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate rules cannot be run on existing records unless you have Performance/Unlimited Edition, in which case you can run [Duplicate Jobs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_jobs_run_and_manage.htm&type=5).

If you have Enterprise Edition, you must use a 3rd party app to de-duplicate existing records.